# Any JS polyfills out there that will take properties like RGBA and convert them to rough IE equivalents?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rgba

So lately I've been enjoying using [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) and while for awhile I didn't believe in doing post-processing using JS, I'm a bit of a believer now.

Now I enjoy using newer properties like 'rgba' and 'text-shadow', but throwing in filters in my CSS file is always unnerving, even if it is pre-processed in PHP.

Are there any tools out there that will take care of applying MS filters and the like for me, while still leaving my CSS untainted from the evil of MS filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some limitation [css3pie](http://css3pie.com) should do what you need. The docs is also very clear.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. My issues with that are - You have to add non-standard CSS mark-up to your pages (Which isn't any better than using filter) and that mark-up in inconsistent (sometimes you have to use behvior, other times you use the `-pie-` prefix. Also, the JavaScript implementation makes it so you have to send a notification to the script for each change you make.